# SpringBoot threw an exception called InvalidStatementException, how to solve it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis

I defined an API in the URL of `/getAppInfo`, and its parameter got only an ID like this:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/getAppInfo")
public ResultResponse getAppInfo(String id) {
    ResultResponse result = new ResultResponse();
    String appName = uploadedFile.getAppInfo(id);
    result.setResult(appName);
    return result;
}
```

The `uploadedFile` is an object of the Interface `IUploadedFileMapper`, and this Mapper reflect a MyBatis  mapper called `UploadedFileMapper.xml`.
Then I wrote down the following codes into `IUploadedFileMapper.java`:

```
public String getAppInfo(String id);
```

After that, I wrote the following codes to `UploadedFileMapper.xml`:

```
<select id="getAppInfo" parameterType="java.lang.String" resultType="java.lang.String">
    select tb.name from table tb where tb.id = #{id} and tb.business_sub_type = 'APP';
</select>
```

By the time I test this WebAPI, the spring-boot then told me:`org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): example.cn.dao.IUploadedFileMapper.getAppInfo`

Comment: Can you remove semicolon from the query and try

Comment: Dear Anish B.: the database is using MySQL and it seems that the semicolon won't affect the program to report an `Invalid bound statement (not found)`, am I right?

Comment: Ok !! Query looks ok. I think the problem might be with Mapper.

Comment: How to say? Any detail, dude?

Comment: Please add more details. Add your Mapper class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i copied your codes and tested.And it was work,so I think your codes is right

Comment: Then maybe my env has some problems. Thx a lot dude.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `table` in SQL select queries

`select tb.name from table tb`

=>

`select tb.name from tb`